# How does $\ln\prod_{i = 1}^n\frac{\Lambda^{x_i}}{x_i!}$ become $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n(x_i\cdot \ln(\Lambda) - \ln(x_i!))$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Could you tell me how I get the sum out of the product?

$$\ln\left(\prod_{i = 1}^n\frac{\Lambda^{x_i}}{x_i!}\right) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n}(x_i\cdot \ln (\Lambda) - \ln(x_i!))$$

Edit: Could this be right? Looks good for me so far...
$$\begin{align}
\ln\left(\prod_{i = 1}^n\frac{\Lambda^{x_i}}{x_i!}\right) 
&= \prod_{i = 1}^n \ln \left(\frac{\Lambda^{x_i}}{x_i!}\right) \tag{1} \\[4pt]
&= \ln \left(\frac{\Lambda^{x_1}}{x_1!}\right) + \cdots + \ln \left(\frac{\Lambda^{x_n}}{x_n!}\right) \tag{2} \\[4pt]
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n\ln \left(\frac{\Lambda^{x_i}}{x_i!}\right) \tag{3} \\[4pt]
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n\ln (\Lambda^{x_i}) - \ln(x_i!) \tag{4} \\[4pt]
&= \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n}(x_i\cdot \ln (\Lambda) - \ln(x_i!)) \tag{5}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Does it help to mention that the "$\ln$" outside the sum on the right-hand side should be removed? (I'm guessing it's a typo.)

Comment: Yes your right its a typo, but the problem ist still there:)

Comment: $\ln (xy) = \ln x + \ln y$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh Im an idiot...

Its $
\ln\left(\prod_{i = 1}^n\frac{\Lambda^{x_i}}{x_i!}\right) 
= \prod_{i = 1}^n ln \left(\frac{\Lambda^{x_i}}{x_i!}\right) 
= ln \left(\frac{\Lambda^{x_1}}{x_1!}\right) + ... + ln \left(\frac{\Lambda^{x_n}}{x_n!}\right) = \sum_{i = 1}^nln \left(\frac{\Lambda^{x_i}}{x_i!}\right) ....
$ right?

Comment: @Joshua.M: Using the line numbers I added ... The right-hand side of line (1) is incorrect (but I don't think you actually *mean* it), but everything thereafter is correct. So, you see that the Log Law $\ln(xy)=\ln x+\ln y$ lets you go directly from the start (left-hand side of (1)) to line (3): a product "inside" the logarithm becomes the sum "outside" the logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

A solution uses logarithm identities: $\ln (xy) = \ln x + \ln y$; $\ln x^y = y \ln x$; and $\ln \frac{x}{y} = \ln x - \ln y$.